# Log4j2 RollingFileAppender not writing logs to file

Tags: java, logging, windows-10, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have the following log4j2 config in ***log4j2.xml*** which is not writing logs to file. I'm using windows 10. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender" fileName="/var/log/abc/test.log"
filePattern="/var/log/abc/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="31"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="Info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Following are the dependencies that I'm using:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.2'
```

Getting the following in my logs:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.xyz.pqr).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Sample code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 

public final class MyUtil { 
      private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUtil.class); 

      if (condition == true) {
          logger.debug("Condition is true."); 
          return false;
      }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: <RollingFile name="RollingFile"..> and <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/> are not matching. Can you change RollingFile to <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender"..>

Comment: I had the same names in the test code, still getting the same issue.

Comment: Your xml worked fine in my machine after fixing naming issue. check whether you are facing any packaging issue.

Comment: Kindly see my updated edit.

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually write a log statement. Including the imports

Comment: It's a project with a lot of files. Sharing only the snippets:

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public final class MyUtil {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUtil.class);
    if (condition == true) {
            logger.debug("Condition is true.");
            return false;
        }
}

Comment: can someone pls help?

Comment: pls help me out on this. reply?

Answer (score 1):

These messages

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.xyz.pqr).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

indicate that log4j 1 is present and something is trying to use it. To resolve that you need to remove the log4j 1.x dependency and replace it with Log4j2's log4j-1.2-api dependency.

Your sample code indicates that you are using the SLF4J API. To bind that with Log4j2 you have to include either log4j-slf4j-impl or log4j-slf4j18-impl depending on the version of SLF4J you are using.

Once you have those dependencies resolved if you still don't see logging add -Dlog4j2.debug=true to the command line. This will log Log4j's initialization to wherever System.out is directed. If you don't see anything then nothing is calling it.